# Ryzen 7 and ASUS Rog, games randomly crash

Tags: memory, crash, amd-ryzen, asus

So Basically I just bought:

- Ryzen 7 2700x
- Asus rog b450-f gaming 2 (with the latest stable bios available)
- Dddr4-3200 corsair vengeance 2x8gb
- GTX 1070 8GB

I have run benchmarks (passmark) and memtest for over an hour without any issues.

Some games like Valhalla and Horizon Zero Down randomly crash when playing (like 1 or 2 minutes into the game).

I have tried to switch the slots of the ram and also tried one stick at time. No results.

What test can I do to understand why these games are crashing ? Note only the game crashes not the windows, I can still close the game and continue working

Temperature are fine (well below 60degress celsius pretty much all the time) and no OC ever

### Edit

<s>So probabily i found the issue: I swtiched the slot of my GPU, it was on the second slot (far from the cpu) I put the gpu on the slot near the CPU and now it seems it's working.... This is so strange</s>: nope still crashing

### Edit2

After losing my mind, I saw on a variety of forums that many people are experiencing these crash with exactly two games:

- Valhalla and
- Horizon zero dawn

At this point I think it's not a fault of my hardware, but it's a bug with these two games

Comment: What graphic card you have , and have you check if motherboard have latest BIOS installed into it .

Comment: gtx 1070 and i have the latest bios. I just bought this mobo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I believe I found the issues: the RAM.

I replaced my `Corsair vengeance 2x8gb` with `Crucial Ballistix BL2K8G30C15U4B 3000 MHz, DDR4` and now it seems to work.

No more crash on Valhalla and Horizon